# Need to bring data from MySQL DB on my PC to Snowflake

Tags: mysql, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[snowflake-cloud-data-platform] Need to bring data from MySQL DB on my PC (Windows operating system) to Snowflake. To load I am using below command -
**put file://D:/Desktop_backup/salary_data_sample2.csv @my_mysql_stage auto_compress=true;**

and I am getting below error -

**SQL compilation error: The command is not supported from the UI: PUT**

Can anyone please post a sample code?
Is there any direct method to put data into Snowflake straight from MySQL DB, without downloading data into CSV format?

Comment: From the error message, it looks like you are using the  Snowflake UI. You need to be using the SnowSQL command line

Answer (score 0):

> *SQL compilation error: The command is not supported from the UI: PUT*

The error is self-explanatory, the PUT cannot be run via WebUI.

> [PUT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html)
>
> **The command cannot be executed from the Worksheets Worksheet tab page in the Snowflake web interface;** instead, use the SnowSQL client to upload data files, or check the documentation for a specific Snowflake client to verify support for this command.

---

> *Is there any direct method to put data into Snowflake straight from MySQL DB, without downloading data into CSV format?*

Yes, you can use any kind of ETL tools/cloud service available on the market that supports MySQL as source and Snowflake as target.